# Express.js app works fine locally but doesn't work when deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm currently trying to deploy a music visualizer that I built. It works in all scenarios except when I click on a song to play from the search bar. I keep on getting '503 (Service Unavailable)'. Does anyone know what's up with my code? I've spent the past 6 hours on SO trying to find the answer, but I've come up with nothing.

Here are my Heroku logs:

```
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757554+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:183
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757570+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757572+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757573+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757574+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757576+00:00 app[web.1]:     at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:254:10)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757577+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:288:21)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757578+00:00 app[web.1]:     at PassThrough.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:563:10)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757581+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitThree (events.js:141:20)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:217:7)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitThree (events.js:136:13)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at FfmpegCommand.emit (events.js:217:7)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757586+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitEnd (/app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:424:16)
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757588+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:433:16
2018-08-10T01:47:00.757589+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
2018-08-10T01:47:00.765330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-08-10T01:47:00.765674+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2018-08-10T01:47:00.766812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! yuen@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2018-08-10T01:47:00.766955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2018-08-10T01:47:00.767136+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2018-08-10T01:47:00.767256+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the yuen@1.0.0 start script.
2018-08-10T01:47:00.767393+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-08-10T01:47:00.771128+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-10T01:47:00.771274+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-08-10T01:47:00.771356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-08-10T01_47_00_768Z-debug.log
```

Here is the source code for my Express app (`server.js`):

```
var express = require('express');
var youtubeStream = require('youtube-audio-stream');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/stream/:videoId', function (req, res) {
    try {
        youtubeStream(req.params.videoId).pipe(res);
    } catch (exception) {
        res.status(500).send(exception);
    }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('app is listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Here is the code that actually interacts with the server by sending xhr requests:

```
function loadSound(vidID) {
    context.close()
    .then(() => {
        context = new AudioContext();
        analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        analyser.fftSize = 32;
    })
    .then(() => {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", window.location.href+"stream/"+vidID, true); 
        request.responseType = "arraybuffer"; 
        request.onload = function() {
            var Data = request.response;
            process(Data);
        };
        request.send();
    });
}
function process(Data) {
    source = context.createBufferSource();
    context.decodeAudioData(Data, function(buffer){
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.connect(analyser);
        source.start(context.currentTime);
    });
    document.getElementById('searchBar').disabled = false;
    loading(true);
}
```

And lastly, here are the listed dependencies in my `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "through2": "^2.0.3",
    "xtend": "^4.0.1",
    "youtube-audio-stream": "https://github.com/cryptagoras/youtube-audio-stream/archive/patch-3.tar.gz",
    "ytdl-core": "^0.24.0"
  }
```

Comment: Do you have `ffmeg` installed on your heroku dyno? [youtube-audio-stream README](https://github.com/JamesKyburz/youtube-audio-stream#youtube-audio-stream): "You will need to have ffmeg and the necessary encoding libraries installed, as well as in your PATH."

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're installed on my heroku dyno... I updated the question to include the dependencies that I've listed in `package.json`!

Comment: I tried your code locally and get the same error **Invalid non-string/buffer chunk**. Also in docs for **ffmpeg** I found: "*To use this library requires that ffmpeg is already installed (including all necessary encoding libraries like libmp3lame or libx264)*". It means it is not enough to have `ffmpeg` node package installed, you have to install libs as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to all of this. Where do I find the necessary additional libs/packages?

Comment: it is a good question. if I find the answer then I will post it here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, I'm not sure if this is helpful, but I ran `npm ls -g --depth=0` in my local environment and I got this output:

`/usr/local/lib`
`create-react-app@1.5.2`
`n@2.1.10`
`npm@6.3.0`

I'm assuming that these are my global npm modules?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: I didn't actually have any of the encoding libraries installed on Heroku. I simply added `ffmpeg` into my `.buildpacks`, and now everything works like a charm!

Comment: Nice! I'm glad that you sorted it out.